# Determine final player in a counting game

Tags: swift, ios

I made a function in which 17 players are counting to number N. Function as a parameter takes a number N and returns which player is going to say N. If current number is divisible by 9 the counting order is reversed, and if current number is divisible by 17 the next player is skipped. I made this code, but is a little bit too big for me, so I wonder if there is another (less code) way I could solve it.

```
func playertold(number: Int)  {

var currentNumber:Int = 1
var currentPlayer:Int = 1
var reversedOrder:Bool = false

while currentNumber != number {
    
    if currentNumber % 9 == 0 {
        
        reversedOrder = !reversedOrder
        
    }
    
    if  currentNumber % 17 == 0 {
        if reversedOrder {
            if currentPlayer == 2 {
                currentPlayer = 17
            } else if currentPlayer == 1 {
                currentPlayer = 16
            } else {
                currentPlayer -= 2
            }
        } else{
            if currentPlayer == 16 {
                currentPlayer = 1
            }else if currentPlayer == 17 {
                currentPlayer = 2
            }else {
                currentPlayer += 2
            }
        }
    } else {
    
    if reversedOrder {
        currentPlayer -= 1
        
        if currentPlayer < 1 {
            currentPlayer = 17
        }
    } else {
        currentPlayer += 1
        
        if currentPlayer > 17 {
            currentPlayer = 1
        }
    }
    }
    
    currentNumber += 1
    
}

print("Player who will say number \(number) is \(currentPlayer)")
}
```

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change the question title (inspired by what I found [here](https://austinwsmith.wordpress.com/2017/04/29/pseudo-code-game/)). Feel free to  edit the title if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

#### General remarks

- The computation should be separated from the program output. That increases the clarity of the program, and makes the functions better testable. In your case, `func playertold` should return the result instead of printing it.
- Type annotations are often not needed, e.g.

  ```
  var currentNumber:Int = 1
  var currentPlayer:Int = 1
  var reversedOrder:Bool = false
  ```

  can be simplified to

  ```
  var currentNumber = 1
  var currentPlayer = 1
  var reversedOrder = false
  ```
- The indending and spacing it not consistent: The function body and some blocks are not indented, some empty lines are superfluous.

#### Simplify the program logic

The while-loop

```
var currentNumber:Int = 1
while currentNumber != number {
    // ... do something ...
    currentNumber += 1
}
```

can be simplified to a for-loop over a range:

```
for currentNumber in 1..<number {
    // ... do something ...
}
```

Instead of a boolean variable `reversedOrder` you can use a integer variable `direction` which holds the values `+1` or `-1`. Advancing to the next player is then done with

```
currentPlayer += direction
// or:
currentPlayer += 2 * direction
```

depending on whether the next player is skipped or not. *After* updating the `currentPlayer` one can check for wrap-around. That saves a lot of case distinctions.

Instead of the remainder operator `%` can can use the `isMultiple(of:)` method which was [introduced in Swift 5](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0225-binaryinteger-iseven-isodd-ismultiple.md), which expresses the intent better.

The function would then look like this:

```
func playertold(number: Int) -> Int {
    var currentPlayer = 1
    var direction = +1
    
    for currentNumber in 1..<number {
        if currentNumber.isMultiple(of: 9) {
            direction = -direction
        }
        // Advance position:
        if currentNumber.isMultiple(of: 17) {
            currentPlayer += 2 * direction
        } else {
            currentPlayer += direction
        }
        // Check for wrap-around:
        if currentPlayer < 1 {
            currentPlayer += 17
        } else if currentPlayer > 17 {
            currentPlayer -= 17
        }
    }
    return currentPlayer
}
```

#### More suggestions

Avoid “magic constants.” In this function that are the numbers 9 and 17, and the latter has two different meanings. What if you want to change the number of players from 17 to 20? In your original code you would have to replace multiple instances of 16 and 17, and in the above version you still have to multiple instances of 17 – but not the 17 in the `isMultiple(of: 17)` check! That is too error-prone.

One option is to define constants, e.g.

```
let numPlayers = 17
let reversePosition = 9
let skipPosition = 17
```

Another – more flexible – option is to make these additional parameters of the function, with default values:

```
func playertold(number: Int, numPlayers: Int = 17,
                reversePosition: Int = 9, skipPosition: Int = 17) -> Int {
    var currentPlayer = 1
    var direction = +1
    
    for currentNumber in 1..<number {
        if currentNumber.isMultiple(of: reversePosition) {
            direction = -direction
        }
        // Advance position:
        if currentNumber.isMultiple(of: skipPosition) {
            currentPlayer += 2 * direction
        } else {
            currentPlayer += direction
        }
        // Check for wrap-around:
        if currentPlayer < 1 {
            currentPlayer += numPlayers
        } else if currentPlayer > numPlayers {
            currentPlayer -= numPlayers
        }
    }
    return currentPlayer
}
```

Now the intent of every constant is clear. The function can still be called with
the standard values

```
print(playertold(number: 1234))
```

but also with custom values

```
print(playertold(number: 1234, numPlayers: 20, reversePosition: 5, skipPosition: 15))
```

Answer (score 1):

## General remarks

- Apart from the name of the function, the names of the variables are
  well-chosen. According to the official [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/):

  > Name functions and methods according to their side-effects:
  > Those without side-effects should read as noun phrases

  Here are some possible alternatives: `playerWhoSays(number:)`, `playerWhoSays(_ number:)`, `player(whoSays number:)`. It would feel more fluent and descriptive.
- You are unnecessarily using a `while` loop to increase `currentNumber` by `1` until it reaches `number`. Since the number of iterations is already known, this is the place to use `for` loops. As an added bonus, `for` loops are faster than `while` loops.
- To make the additions a little faster, use [the overflow addition operator: `&+`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2964457).

## Deeper understanding of the problem

[image: Scatter plot]

1. This function is periodic:

   - It increases by nine and then decreases by nine : `9 (first half) + 9 (second half)`; we'll call this a ***cycle***.
   - Every 17 numbers, we skip a player.
     Since 18 and 17 are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) (their Greatest Common Divisor is 1), then, the period **P** of this function is:

$$ P = 17 \cdot (9 + 9) = 306 $$

It will suffice to calculate the result for a number between `1` and `306` that is away x times from the initial number. This operation is similar to a regular modulo:

```swift
if number > 306 {
    number = ((number - 1) % 306) + 1
}
```

2. There is an axis of partial vertical [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function) in each period **P**:

   - The starting point of each *cycle* will be decreasing from one cycle to the next, as long as the player to be skipped is in the second half of each cycle. This will be reversed once the player to be skipped is in the first half of a cycle.
   - e.g., this function will symmetrical output when we skip `17` or `2`.
   - This axis of symmetry will be reached once the number to be skipped is in the middle of a *cycle*. So, the abscissa of this axis is at:

$$ Number = 18 \cdot (18 / 2) = 18 \cdot 9 = 162 $$

3. For the first nine *cycles*, (on the left side of the origin of symmetry), no numbers are skipped in the first half of the cycle.
4. If a number is in the second half of a cycle, we'll have to take skips into consideration.

## The new algorithm

Taking all the above into consideration, here is the new algorithm:

```swift
func player(whoSays number: Int) -> Int {
    var n = number
    
    //Periodicity
    if n > 306 {
        n = ((n - 1) % 306) + 1
    }
    
    //Partial symmetry
    n = min(n, 324 - n)
    
    // q : the cycle order; r : the position of a number inside the cycle
    let (q, r) = n.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 18)
    
    let startOfCycle = max(1, (18 - q) % 18)
    let endOfCycle = 17 - q
    var player = 0
    
    if r <= 9 { //First half of the cycle
        player = startOfCycle + r - 1
        return ((player - 1) % 17) + 1
    }
    else { //Second half of a cycle
        player = endOfCycle + (18 - r)
        let seventeenMultiple = (n / 17) * 17
        let nineMultiple = ((n - 1) / 9) * 9
        // We check if a skip happened in the second half of a cycle before the number
        if seventeenMultiple >= nineMultiple && seventeenMultiple != n {
            player -= 1
        }
    }
    return ((player - 1) % 17) + 1
}
```

- [The time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of this algorithm is \$ O(1) \$.